# Looking for that passage or verse from Ramayana where Rama acknowldeges the power of Bhakti

Tags: ramayana, rama, identification-request, hanuman, bhakti

So pleased with Hanuman at a certain time in Ramayana Lord Rama declares that by dint of his love and Bhakthi Hanuman has become in fact even more powerful than himself (Rama)... a sort of win-over. Can someone cite this sloka or passage? I heard it a long time ago, but not the yathra yathra Raghunatha Samkirthanam one.